# Change PyDev way of indenting function argument

Tags: python, ide, pydev, readability

I'd like to use PEP8 accepted format:

```
# Hanging indents should add a level.
foo = long_function_name(
    var_one, var_two,
    var_three, var_four)
```

How to configure PyDev so when I open bracket and press Enter it moves caret to next line with increased indentation by one level? Currently after hitting Enter caret is set just below openning bracket.

Is it configurable at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure that at:

Preferences > PyDev > editor > Typing > After '(' indent to its level (indents by tabs if unchecked).

Comment: Thanks, I entirely missed 'Typing' section.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to utilize `\` but before you do that you need to put at least one after calling the function.

```
def superlongfunction(one,\
                      two):
    return(one+two)

foo = superlongfunction(5,\
                        2)
```

Edit: That's what I'm used to do for visualization. I tried without `\` and it worked, but you *must* have at least one right after calling the function.

```
foo = superlongfunction(5,
                        2)
```